# How do I negatively pattern match in a bash script file?

Tags: linux, bash

If I type `rm main!(.tex|.pdf)` into a bash terminal, it will delete all files that start with `main` but do not end in `.tex` or `.pdf`, clearing up various junk files that are strewn around by LaTeX typesetters.

The following shell script, however, doesn't do what I expect it to when placed in a file and then run

```
#!/bin/bash

rm main!(.tex|.pdf)
```

A syntax error is reported at the `(` token. What gives? What's the canonical way of doing something like this as part of a bash script. Is there are more elegant way of doing this than bringin `find` to bear against the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern does not work when run from a script, make sure that the `extglob` option is set for non-interactive use, too.

Just put

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
```

on top of your script after the hashbang. That way it's easy to spot. See also: [Glob – Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)